# awk lines in file between header and footer strings

Tags: variables, awk, header

I'm trying to parse out all of the lines in between different headers and footers to different files using an awk script in a for loop. For example, I have a file with a list of mismatches with sample-name headers (**compiled.csv**) that looks like this:

```
19-T00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1557,WT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,109-G->A,110-G->A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,183-G->A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
19-T10,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
642,WT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
206,24->G,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
19-T21,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
464,24->G,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
19-TSpl,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2219,24->G,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20-T00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
...
...
```

My goal for the lines above would be to pass all the lines from the `19-T00` to the `2219,24->G,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` in a sample output file called `sample-19.csv`.

The sample names all share the pattern `[0-9][0-9]-T*`. And my approach to doing this first was based on creating an array with all 20 sample names (i.e. 19, 20, 21...). I am trying to execute the following loop, and output files are created but they are blank.

```
for i in {0,19}
do a="$i"
b=`echo $i+1 | bc`
header="${array[$a]}-T"; footer="${array[$b]}-T"
name=`echo $header | cut -d"-" -f1`
awk -F, -v start="$header" -v finish="$footer" '/^start*/,/^finish*/' compiled.csv >"sample-"$name".csv"
done
```

If I do this manually with the one-liner: 
`awk '/^19-T*/,/^20-T*/' compiled.csv >sample-19.csv` it works fine. So I think there may be a problem in the variable passing, but I don't know how to fix it.

I know there are some other threads discussing the header-footer approach using awk, but I just think my syntax needs some help. If anyone has any advice by way of more experienced eyes, it would be much appreciated. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is something like this (untested):

```
awk '
/^[0-9][0-9]-T00,/ {
    close(out)
    out = "sample-" $0
    sub(/-T00.*/,".csv",out)
}
{ print > out }
' compiled.csv
```

If you're ever again considering processing text with a shell loop make sure to read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) first

Comment: Thanks for this Ed. As a newbie to text processing, however, do you think you could explain what part of the code is outputting the lines prior to the next 'T00'? And thanks for the link to better processing...always looking to improve here.

Comment: Never mind, I sat down and thought of it more without overcomplicating it and it makes sense. Stupid question, but thanks, still, for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

using `awk`

```
awk --posix '/[0-9]{2}-T00/{split($0,a,"-"); name=a[1]} {print $0>"sample-"name".cas"}' file
```

Output will be two files "sample-19.csv" and "sample-20.csv" for your contents

Comment: That will fail with some awks as it's undefined behavior to have an unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection. It's gawk-specific due to the use of `--posix` so idk what the point is of using that flag. You don;t need the `$0` in the print. With non-GNU awks you'll have to close the output files as they change if the input file is large. It'll also fail if a string matching the first regexp appears anywhere on the line.